# Bootstrap Navigation Issue: Can't Change the Background Color of Different Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a real estate website project. I have already created Photoshop template and uploaded it on Behance. 
https://www.behance.net/csc103falld848
https://www.behance.net/gallery/66727753/Blog-Design

Right now, I am creating the static version of the real estate store template.

I am facing an issue. In the navigation, I can't change the background color of different columns. For example, the background color of phone number (1-800-000) should be silver. On the other hand, the background color of "Login," "My Properties," and "Favorites" should be white. But I can't change it.

Here is the HTML codes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kanon's Smartphone Store</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- FontAwesome icon fonts -->
        <link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Custom Theme files -->
<!--        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />-->
<!--        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />-->
        <link href="css/fasthover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/popuo-box.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <!-- //Custom Theme files -->


        <!-- Website Logo -->

        <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/KS%20Large.jpg">

        <!-- Animate.css -->
        <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </head>

<body>

    <section id="navigation">

    <header class="site-header" role="banner">

        <nav class="navbar-custom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                  </button>
                </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="store.html">Apartments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">Townhouses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-2 logo-1">


                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
<!--
                            <div id="rectangle">
                            <div class="col-md-2 phone-1">

                            <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-phone"></i>1-800-000</a></li>
                            </div>
                            </div>
-->
                            <div class="col-md-10">

                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">


                        <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-phone"></i>1-800-000</a></li>

                        <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Login/Sign up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-building"></i>My Properties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-star"></i>Favorites</a></li>

                  </ul>    
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

                        <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>Location (Any)</a></li>

                        <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>Property Type (Any)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html"><i id="home-font-awesome-icon" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>Property Status (Any)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Search Here</a></li>

                  </ul>


                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            </div>







</nav> 

    </header>
    </section>
```

Here is the CSS codes:

```
.navbar-custom{

    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 400px;
}

.navbar-brand{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.navbar-brand:hover{
    color: #00ff00;
    font-weight: bolder;
}



.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bolder;

}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left .active{
    background-color:#F0B616;
    font-weight: bolder;

}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a:hover {
    background-color: wheat;
    color: #00ff00;
}

.icon-bar {
    background-color:#FF0000 !important;
 }

#home-font-awesome-icon{
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.logo-1 {
    background: url(../img/Golden-real-estate-logo-vector.jpg);
    height: 15%;
    width: 15%;

    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;  
}

.phone-1 {

background-color: azure;    
}
```

Here is the Codepen.io link:
https://codepen.io/kanan292/pen/xJzygG

I am really passionate about coding. I really need your help to complete this project. Then I will be able to move on backend development either with WordPress or Django or ASP.NET Core.

Looking forward to getting a great solution from you.

Comment: Your code snippet is not working properly in CodePen - you haven't adjusted any of the URLs for things like stylesheets, fonts, images etc. so they are not going to work because they do not exist in that location, e.g.

<link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

and that simply does not exist. Reference the relevant files properly within CodePen by adding external stylesheets etc within the pen and then it will actually look like the the PSD and people can help you more easily.

Comment: @Raad I have added the external stylesheet and bootstrap link. But still, it doesn't look OK. Would you please take a look at these two links? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBXzjK   https://codepen.io/kanan292/pen/xJzygG

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to work out for me check this out => https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBXzjK

```
.phone-1{
 background-color: black;
 }

.navbar-nav li:nth-child(2){
 background-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the navigation of this link:https://www.behance.net/gallery/66727753/Blog-Design . Instead, it looks like this one:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aJniAIUAX7M8VR2F5p6YEIASWDRGV1sr